# Distance of Limit Point of Subset of Metric Space from that Subset

Tags: limits, metric-spaces

During the course of working through exercises in various elementary topology works, we come to the question where we have to prove something along the lines that:

if $K$ is closed in a metric space $M = (A, d)$, then $d (K, x) = 0 \iff x$ is a limit point of $K$

or:

$K$ is closed iff ($d (K, x) = 0 \implies x$ is a limit point of $K$)

or however it is presented.

Both of these results is directly dependent upon what appears to be a much more fundamental result:

$d (K, x) = 0$ iff $x$ is a limit point of $K$

This is so straightforward to prove that even I can do it:

**Necessary Condition**

Let $x$ be a limit point of $K$.

Aiming for a contradiction, suppose $d (K, x) \ne 0$.

By definition of metric, that means:
$$d (K, x) > 0$$

Hence:
$$\forall y \in K: d (x, y) > 0$$

Then:
$$\exists \epsilon \in \mathbb R_{>0}: \forall y \in K: d (x, y) > \epsilon$$

That is:
$$\forall y \in H: y \notin B_\epsilon (x) \setminus \{x\}$$

where $B_\epsilon (x) \setminus \{x\}$ denotes the deleted $\epsilon$-neighborhood of $x$

That is:
$$(B_\epsilon (x) \setminus \{x\}) \cap H = \varnothing$$

Hence, by definition, $x$ is not a limit point of $H$.

From this contradiction it follows that it cannot be the case that $$d (K, x) \ne 0$$

That is:
$$d (K, x) = 0$$
$\Box$

**Sufficient Condition**

Let $d (K, x) = 0$.

Aiming for a contradiction, suppose $x$ is not a limit point of $H$.

Then, by definition, it is not the case that:
$$\forall \epsilon \in \mathbb R_{>0}: \{y \in H: 0 < d (y, x) < \epsilon\} \ne \varnothing$$

So:
$$\exists \epsilon \in \mathbb R_{>0}: \{y \in H: 0 < d (y, x) < \epsilon\} = \varnothing$$

which means:
$$\exists \epsilon \in \mathbb R_{>0}: \forall y \in H: d (y, x) \ge \epsilon$$

That is:
$$\inf_{y \mathop \in K} (d (y, x)) \ge \epsilon$$

By definition of the distance between $x$ and $K$:
$$d (x, K) \ge \epsilon > 0$$

From this contradiction it follows that it cannot be the case that $x$ is not a limit point of $K$.

That is:

$x$ is a limit point of $K$.

$\blacksquare$

I've taken great care to hammer this out carefully, and it may not be the most streamlined proof of this ever. But the point is, despite the fact that this is a pretty fundamental result, it is rare to find it explicitly presented (in other words, in the topology books that I've studied properly, it isn't).

Is it *actually* correct, and have I proved it properly?

If not, then where am I going wrong?

As I say, I intend to use it as a basic lemma in the result(s) stated at the start of this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $K$ is a subset of a metric space and $x$ is a point in the space.

It is true that, if $x$ is a limit point of $K$, then $d(x,K)=0$.

It is **not** true, that, if $d(x,K)=0$, then $x$ is a limit point of $K$. For example, in the space $\mathbb R$, if $K=\mathbb Z$ and $x\in\mathbb Z$, then $d(x,K)=0$ but $x$ is not a limit point of the set $K$, which has no limit points.

A correct statement: $d(x,K)=0$ if and only if $x$ is a limit point or an element of $K$; in other words, $d(x,K)=0$ if and only if $x$ belongs to the closure of $K$.

The statement
$$\forall y\in K:d(x,y)\gt0$$
is equivalent to $x\notin K$, and certainly does not imply the existence of a positive number $\epsilon$ such that $d(x,y)\gt\epsilon$ for all $y\in K$.

However, if we assume that $d(x,K)\gt0$, then such an $\epsilon$ does exist, for instance $\epsilon=d(x,y)/2$.

Comment: An absolutely perfect answer. Respect.

Comment: Having worked my way through this and its implications, I wonder why the point is not laboured more in the text books.